# how to create java pattern for validate document ids of firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pattern-matching

I want to create a java pattern for validate document id in firestore.
The pattern should match the following conditions

- Must be valid UTF-8 characters
- Cannot contain a forward slash (/)
- Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
- Cannot match the regular expression    **.***
- Cannot contain white spaces

I have created a pattern only for double periods (..)

```
Pattern.compile("^((?!\\.\\.).)*\$").matcher(shopCode).matches();
```

How can i create a pattern which satisfies all the conditions given above?

Comment: where are your code trials?

Comment: What have you tried so far?